# How can I sort a list with major.minor.patch level and sometimes rc correctly?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, python, sort

I have to sort the following list with a shell script and make the latest version appear on the bottom or top. How would I do that with shell tools only?

```
release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.0
release-5.0.1
release-5.0.10
release-5.0.11
release-5.0.13
release-5.0.14
release-5.0.15
release-5.0.16
release-5.0.17
release-5.0.18
release-5.0.19
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.20
release-5.0.21
release-5.0.22
release-5.0.23
release-5.0.24
release-5.0.25
release-5.0.26
release-5.0.27
release-5.0.28
release-5.0.29
release-5.0.3
```

Comment: See also `printf '%s\n' ${(on)array}` in `zsh`. (when the list is in the `$array` array).

Comment: (1) You should *say* what output you want; don’t assume that it’s intuitively obvious.  Please do not respond in comments (especially not [comments on answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350315/how-can-i-sort-a-list-with-major-minor-patch-level-and-sometimes-rc-correctly/350328#comment621065_350805)); [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  (2) You don’t really need to provide a 25-line input.  As long as you’re skipping 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  and  12, why not also skip 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26  and  27?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

GNU sort has `-V` that can mostly deal with a list like that ([details](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort)):

```
 -V, --version-sort
        natural sort of (version) numbers within text

$ cat vers
release-5.0.19
release-5.0.19~pre1
release-5.0.19-bigbugfix
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.20
$ sort -V vers
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.19~pre1
release-5.0.19
release-5.0.19-bigbugfix
release-5.0.20
```

However, those `.rc*` versions could be a bit of a problem, since they probably should be sorted *before* the corresponding non-rc version, if there happened to be both, that is. Some versioning systems (like Debian's), use suffixes starting with a tilde (`~`) to mark pre-releases, and they sort before the version without a suffix, which sorts before versions with other suffixes. Apparently this is supported by at least the `sort` on my system, as shown above (`sort (GNU coreutils) 8.23`).

To sort the example list, you could use the following:

```bsh
perl -pe 's/\.(?=rc)/~/' < versions.txt | sort -V | perl -pe 's/~/./' > versions-sorted.txt
```

Comment: Sniped me by a couple of seconds :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not even imagine that sort would have an option like that.

Comment: FWIW, `-V` also supported by default `sort` on OpenBSD, but not on NetBSD.

Comment: [FreeBSD too, apparently](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1), the man page there also has an example output order, and looks identical to the OpenBSD one.

Answer (score 9):

Check out `sort -V`:

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Version numbers are complicated beasts, with very few standards governing the alphabetic portions, but try this on your actual data and see if it's sufficient.

Comment: Wow, great! This works even for an old problem of mine with file names `mayorNumber–minorNumer some text`, where field sorting fails because of unicode delimiter. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

This is can be done as one line, but split into multiple lines (at the pipes) here for readability, and handles the `rc`'s, too.

If you don't have a `-V` option for your sort, or even if you do, you'll need to deal with the occasional `rc`’s:

```
cat versionlist |
    sed -e "s/release-//" -e "s/rc//" |
    sort -t. -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 |
    sed -r -e "s/([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)/\1.\2.\3.rc\4/" -e "s/^/release-/"
```

- The first `sed` strips the non-numeric characters. 
  (For this statement, **`.`** is considered to be a numeric character.)
- The `sort` uses a **`.`** delimiter (`-t.`),
  numeric sort (`-n`), and enumerates fields 1, 2, 3 and 4 as keys (`-k`).
- The final `sed` puts the non-numeric characters back in place
  (assuming that *every* line in the input had them).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the inspiration - May i propose my own answer:
The sort programm can be tricked into doing what is needed. In the end it is about adding a fourth number to the the 3 digit versioning , sort it, and then remove it again. Works - simplest solution so far, IMHO.

```
cat versionlist |\
sed -r "s/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$)/\1\.99999/"|sort -V|sed s/\.99999$//
```

result:

```
release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.0

....
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, this method would work. It appends a trailing `|` to every line before applying `sort -V`, then removes the trailing `|`. The reason is because `sort -V` orders `|` after all ascii characters except for `}`.

```bsh
$ cat versions.txt | sed 's/$/|/' | sort -V | sed 's/|$//'

release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.0
release-5.0.1
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.10
release-5.0.11
```

---

However, if you add `release-5.0.0.rc` to the list, then you need a more complex command. This will temporarily remove `release-` and add a trailing `|` only to the lines without `rc` (or any other `[a-zA-Z]`).

```bsh
$ cat versions.txt | 
sed -e 's/^release-//' -e '/[a-zA-Z]/! s/$/|/' | 
sort -V | 
sed -e 's/^/release-/' -e 's/|$//'

release-5.0.0.rc
release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.0
release-5.0.1
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.10
release-5.0.11
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.tmp
release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.0
release-5.0.1
release-5.0.10
release-5.0.11
release-5.0.13
release-5.0.14
release-5.0.15
release-5.0.16
release-5.0.17
release-5.0.18
release-5.0.19
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.20
release-5.0.21
release-5.0.22
release-5.0.23
release-5.0.24
release-5.0.25
release-5.0.26
release-5.0.27
release-5.0.28
release-5.0.29
release-5.0.3

$ cat /tmp/tmp.tmp | awk -F\- '{ print $2,$1 }' | sort -n | awk '{ print $2 "-" $1 }'
release-5.0.0
release-5.0.0.rc1
release-5.0.0.rc2
release-5.0.1
release-5.0.10
release-5.0.11
release-5.0.13
release-5.0.14
release-5.0.15
release-5.0.16
release-5.0.17
release-5.0.18
release-5.0.19
release-5.0.2
release-5.0.20
release-5.0.21
release-5.0.22
release-5.0.23
release-5.0.24
release-5.0.25
release-5.0.26
release-5.0.27
release-5.0.28
release-5.0.29
release-5.0.3

$
```

Comment: release-5.0.0 should come AFTER .rc1 and .rc2 in the list. that is the challenge here.

Comment: More importantly, `5.0.2` and `5.0.3` should come before `5.0.10`.

Comment: In the sorted output, they do @G-Man

Comment: (1) No, they don’t — I tried it.  (2) You ***show*** the output in your answer, and it shows 5.0.2 coming after 5.0.19, and 5.0.3 coming after 5.0.29.