# How to sort by numeric (logic) ascending but alphabetic order with Debian

Tags: debian, sort

Assume I have a list of parsed version tags like

```
0.2
0.1
0.10
0.9
```

If I use `sort` I get
(Am I right, this is called the collation order?)

```
0.1
0.10
0.2
0.9
```

If I want the numeric (logic) order I'd expect

```
0.1
0.2
0.9
0.10
```

This, for example, is a scenario I often get in touch with, once I parse package releases while I want to get the latest version for automated installation processes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related: [How can I sort a list with major.minor.patch level and sometimes rc correctly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350315/how-can-i-sort-a-list-with-major-minor-patch-level-and-sometimes-rc-correctly)

Comment: This option is on the screen with `man` without any scrolling. How did I miss it? Thx, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU sort has the `-V`/`--version-sort` option meant just for sorting version numbers. It produces exactly the output you want, and also deals with multipart version numbers like `0.10.123`.

With that particular set of data you could also use `sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n`. That is, to tell `sort` to use `.` as the field separator, and then sort numerically based on the first and second fields in that order. (`-k1n` would use the rest of the line starting at the first field leading to a different result.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thx for the hint `sort -V` is respecting nested versions.

Comment: @BothOfYou Im not on my Debian machine right now to play with. But I recognized the first version of @ilkkachu and his edit. Whats the difference between the first approach with `sort -t. -k1n` and `sort -t. -k1,1n`?

Comment: Sorry. I missed to read the braced part in the answere entirely. So with the multiple `-k` options I can tell sort the order of how to sort in version (natural numerical) order? (Eg. the build version over the minor version?)

Comment: @codekandis, yeah, `-k2,2n -k1,1n` would sort on the second field first, so `0.1 1.1 0.2 1.2`. And `-k1n -k2n` sorts `0.1 0.10 0.2` in that order, since `-k1n` already looks at the whole line and only takes the part before the dot as a number. I always forget you have to add the ending field too (the second `1` in `-k1,1`) to stop that.

Comment: Ok, just by understanding by reading: Why don't just use `sort -k2n -k1n` over `sort -k2,2n -k1,1n`. What's the difference? I try to understand the difference of `-k[x]n` and `-k[x],[x]n` option notation.

Comment: @codekandis, [`-kN,M` tells it to use the fields from N to M as the key, but if M is not given, it defaults to the rest of the line.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) So `-k1,1` tells it to use field #1 only, but `-k1` tells it to use the whole line starting from field #1. With just two fields, `-k2,2 -k1,1` is probably the same as just `-k2 -k1`, since the first key already looked at field #2, so it doesn't matter much if the second key also does (as long as the same sorting rule is used for both). But if you had more than two fields, `-k2,2` would be different from `-k2`.

Comment: I played around with it today depending on your explanations. You focused me right to the point. I appreciate it.